# How do I make a server that receives a http request for this request? How would I also store it?

Tags: python, http, httprequest, http-status-code-404, pythonanywhere

How do I make a server that receives a http request for something like this http get request below:
How would I also store the token in the server?
It also gives error 404

```py
token = requests.get(f"http://ex.example.com/{cookie}")
if token.text=="VALID":
```

I don't know how to get a request and I don't know how to store it.